# Is it possible to 'see' the object graph for garbage collection?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a Java application that is leaking memory. I know which objects are not being freed during garbage collection, but I can't work out what is referencing them.

Is it at all possible to have some sort of visibility of the object graph that is being held internally by the JVM?

It is at all otherwise possible to find out which objects are referencing another object?

Comment: Why can't you reference them when you knoe which objects they are?

Comment: It's a J2ME app. The emulator's memory profiler tells me that there are 2 instances of a class when there should only be 1. Unfortunately it doesn't tell me much more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a really basic level, you can use the commands jhat and jmap to read a heap file from a running Java process and then process it - it starts a small web server on a local port. It's not exactly easy to read, but you don't have to buy a profiler to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Profilers do this. [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/whatsnew51.html) for example. Back in the day I used Optimizeit (which seems to be dead now).

The conclusion was that listeners were being passed to some collection and not being removed from that collection. The listeners were anonymous inner classes defined on a Frame or a corresponding control class that referenced the Frame, and an anonymous inner class has an implicit reference to its outer class. So that little listener held the whole frame and all its attendant objects in active memory.