# get object tree

Tags: java, garbage-collection, reachability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to ‘see’ the object graph for garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238629/is-it-possible-to-see-the-object-graph-for-garbage-collection)

Are there any virtual machine or library that provides access to object graph?
I need to know if the specific object is reachable from some set of objects that I treat as root.

I want to implement memory leak checking in unit tests.